# jQuery: If button is "hover", change style in NEXT button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have problem witch change style border-left-color in next button, if main button is hover, and I need same function for "focus" => if main button is "focus".

Thanks for help

```
$("button").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).nex("button").css("border-left-color", "#6e6e6e");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).nex("button").css("border-left-color", "#bdbdbd");
    }
);
```

Comment: First off the correct method is `next()`. However to give you a full answer, we'll need to see the HTML code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS only:

```
button:hover + button {border-left-color: #6e6e6e;}
```